# Бот не отправляет сообщение в канал, но при этом ошибок нет

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Бот не отправляет сообщение в указанный канал, хотя в консоли никаких ошибок не появляется. Как будто бот выполнил код, но при этом в этом коде не было отправки сообщения.
Код команды:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["хелп"])
async def help(ctx, * command):
    clr = discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    cnl = ctx.message.channel
    if (command == None or command == ""):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="General help", type="rich", colour=clr)
        modcom = """ban, unban, kick, mute, unmute, warn, rmwarn, warns, snipe, lockdown, unlockdown, role, roles, hierarchy"""
        muscom = """join, leave, play, pause, stop, skip, voteskip"""
        uticom = """search, """
        maicom = """about, help, serverinfo, userinfo"""
        emb.add_field(name="Information", value=maicom)
        emb.add_field(name="Moderation", value=modcom)
        emb.add_field(name="Music", value=muscom)
        emb.add_field(name="Utilities", value=uticom)
        await cnl.send(embed=emb)
    elif (command == "ban" or command == "бан"):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Help on command **{command}**", type="rich", colour=clr)
        emb.add_field(name="Use:", value="!ban <mention | id> <reason>")
        emb.add_field(name="Description:", value="Bans a member from current guild by id or mention.")
        emb.add_field(name="Aliases", value="бан")
        await cnl.send(embed=emb)
```

Вид консоли после отправки `!help`:
[![Вид консоли][1]][1]
В канале дискорда никаких сообщений от бота не появилось, при этом все остальные команды работают на ура.
Подскажите как это исправить и что я делаю не так?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZzYD.png

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в единственной запятой, не поставленной после * , в строке 2..

- Спасибо за ответ дискорд серверу Fadager!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ваша главная ошибка в том, что вы забыли 1 запятую.
Вот как должен выглядить код:

````
async def help(ctx, *, command):  # тут пропущена запятая. вот и вся ошибка.
    clr = discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    cnl = ctx.message.channel
    if (command == None or command == ""):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="General help", type="rich", colour=clr)
        modcom = """ban, unban, kick, mute, unmute, warn, rmwarn, warns, snipe, lockdown, unlockdown, role, roles, hierarchy"""
        muscom = """join, leave, play, pause, stop, skip, voteskip"""
        uticom = """search, """
        maicom = """about, help, serverinfo, userinfo"""
        emb.add_field(name="Information", value=maicom)
        emb.add_field(name="Moderation", value=modcom)
        emb.add_field(name="Music", value=muscom)
        emb.add_field(name="Utilities", value=uticom)
        await cnl.send(embed=emb)
    elif (command == "ban" or command == "бан"):
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Help on command **{command}**", type="rich", colour=clr)
        emb.add_field(name="Use:", value="!ban <mention | id> <reason>")
        emb.add_field(name="Description:", value="Bans a member from current guild by id or mention.")
        emb.add_field(name="Aliases", value="бан")
        await cnl.send(embed=emb)```
````

Comment: Если вы не заметили, мне уже ответили на вопрос, хоть и не здесь.